# How to add an admin page for a custom widget in Socialengine 4

Tags: php, zend-framework, socialengine

How can we create an administration panel page for a custom widget in social engine 4?
I have not found any information regarding this over the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a controller, for example, 'AdminSettingsController.php' in application/modules/Yourmodule/controllers/

In this controller:

```
class User_AdminManageController extends Core_Controller_Action_Admin
```

Then create `public function indexAction()` inside. It will contain all your code related to your custom widget.

After that you should create a view in application/modules/Yourmodule/views/scripts/admin-settings/ called 'index.tpl'.

Now you can access your administration panel page by the link yoursite.com/admin/yourmodule/settings

Hope this helps.