# How to get data from database in controller and show them in view in Social Engine admin panel

Tags: view, module, controller, widget, socialengine

How can I create a page in admin panel controller to get data and show them in view? I have read [How to add an admin page for a custom widget in Socialengine 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14750884/how-to-add-an-admin-page-for-a-custom-widget-in-socialengine-4/15091069) but it didn't work. I think I should do something with manifest. If yes what should I include there?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to create public function in admin core controller and create a view with the same name and call model to get data from database, but that is not recomended due to future upgrades of SE.

Better to create a plugin from admin -> Develoepr SDK (/install/sdk/create) and in the package, write query for admin menu under settings/my.sql file, like this

INSERT IGNORE INTO `engine4_core_menuitems` (`name`, `module`, `label`, `plugin`, `params`, `menu`, `submenu`, `order`) VALUES

('#modulename#_adminsettings_main', '#modulename#', 'Module Title', '', '{"route":"#modulename#_admin"}', 'core_admin_main_plugins', '', 999);

## modulename# = your module name provided by Developer SDK.

Now create a controller with the name of admin and model files with the name of table.

You can define the route under settings/manifest.php file.

Also, check existing modules code, you will get better idea for the same.

Hope above information will help you.

Comment: I have created controller and view and don't need to get data from db just by now. But it doesn't even echo out the value of the variable. It doesn't even call indexAction method in which die('something'); is inside. @vipinbairagi

Comment: what should I put in settings/manifest.php? I have entered some routes but they may be wrong! could you tell me the correct form?

Comment: @codepro you need to write route in manifest.php file for controller method.

Comment: I have been trying hard and lastly I could get the hello world but now I want to fetch the data from database and show them in the page. How can I do that? @vipinbairagi

Comment: let me know db table, I will provide you example based on that - @codepro

Comment: I have created a table named engine4_articlemanagement_articles. As I read the format should be: prefix_module_table, however when I created a model in Model and DbTable, and when I wanted to instantiate it didn't work! I really appreciate if you tell me how I can select from this table and afterwards update it. THANKS @vipinbairagi